# Could function theoretically exit too early?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Would it be possible for the function to exit/close down before the document gets updated, and thus the doc not get updated?
More comments in code:

```js
exports.enterToWin = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {
  const { user } = data;

  try {
    return await db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
      const ref = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
      const snap = await ref.where('available', '==', true).get();
      const prize = snap.docs[i];

      // See how we're updating the prize here...
      t.update(prize.ref, {
        winner: user,
        available: false
      });

      // ... but we're not waiting for the transaction to complete before returning?
      // Could this cause the update to fail, in theory?
      return { uid: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: 'Unexpected error: ' + error.message };
  }
});
```

Would it be safer/better to wait like this?

```js
await t.update(prize.ref, {
  winner: user,
  available: false
});

return { uid: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
```

Function works great 99% of the time. But we has some issues in production. Some users got a prize but the prize appeared to later vanish. Trying to troubleshoot what actually happened. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible for the function to exit/close down before the document gets updated if the await keyword is not used before returning. I would recommend you to `await` any Promise or use `.then` when possible.

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript asynchronous functions must be awaited otherwise it is entirely possible that the promise will not resolve before the Cloud Function terminates. This is detailed in the Firebase documentation [Sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> It's important to manage the lifecycle of a function to ensure that it resolves properly. By terminating functions correctly, you can avoid excessive charges from functions that run for too long or loop infinitely. Also, you can make sure that the Cloud Functions instance running your function does not shut down before your function successfully reaches its terminating condition or state.
>
> Use these recommended approaches to manage the lifecycle of your functions:
>
> - Resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing (also known as "background functions") by returning a JavaScript promise.

This is further detailed in [The Node.js Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime#signal-termination) documentation for Cloud Functions:

> When working with asynchronous tasks that involve callbacks or `Promise` objects, you must explicitly inform the runtime that your function has finished executing these tasks. You can do this in several different ways, as shown in the samples below. The key is that your code must wait for the asynchronous task or `Promise` to complete before returning; otherwise the asynchronous component of your function may be terminated before it completes.

And again in the [Tips & Tricks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities) documentation for Cloud Functions:

> **Do not start background activities**
>
> Background activity is anything that happens after your function has terminated. A function invocation finishes once the function returns or otherwise signals completion, such as by calling the `callback` argument in Node.js event-driven functions. Any code run after graceful termination cannot access the CPU and will not make any progress.

To directly answer your question, you must `await` calls to `update()` because it is an asynchronous function. You should configure your IDE and/or linter to check for un-awaited asynchronous functions, e.g., with [require-await](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/require-await):

> This rule warns async functions which have no await expression.
>
> Examples of incorrect code for this rule:

```js
/*eslint require-await: "error"*/

async function foo() {
    doSomething();
}

bar(async () => {
    doSomething();
});
```

> Examples of correct code for this rule:

```js
/*eslint require-await: "error"*/

async function foo() {
    await doSomething();
}

bar(async () => {
    await doSomething();
});

function foo() {
    doSomething();
}

bar(() => {
    doSomething();
});

// Allow empty functions.
async function noop() {}
```